# Laptop Is playing music when the screen won't come on

Tags: laptop

im listening to music from ITunes on my laptop and It went off for a couple of seconds and then it shut down but it is still playing music and the computer isn't turning on! Help!!

Comment: How can the computer shut down while the music is still playing? Have you tried to do a hard reboot? Are there still lights on?

Comment: Sounds like the resources needed to sleep are not being properly shifted in priority.  iTunes has this problem with most low end laptops.

Answer (score 0):

Try to power cycle your laptop once using the following steps,

1. Remove power adapter and battery from your laptop
2. Press the power button for 30 secs to drain the leftout power

Then connect battery and try to boot.